# Facebook JS Client-Side Auth not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get the Facebook Javascript SDK Client-Side Authentication working and it does so in Firefox, but it fails miserably in IE.  In IE 8 when I click the login button nothing happens at all.  No overlay, no alert from IE, no nothing.  The code is the sample coded provided by Facebook with VERY little in the way of modifications.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <title>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));

      // Init the SDK upon load
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//thejspot.ws/channel.html', // Path to your Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
            FB.api('/me', function(me){
              if (me.name) {
                document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                oFormObject = document.forms['ri_form'];
                oFormObject.elements['full_name'].value = me.name;
                oFormObject.elements['email_address_'].value = me.email;
                oFormObject.elements['gender'].value = me.gender;
                oFormObject.elements['locale'].value = me.locale;
              }
            })
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
          }
        });

        // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
        document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
          FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'email'});
        });
        document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click', function(){
          FB.logout();
        }); 
      }
    </script>
    <h1>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</h1>
      <div id="auth-status">
        <div id="auth-loggedout">
          <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display:none">
          <span id="auth-displayname"></span> (<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)<br /><br />
          <h3>Facebook Attributes</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="get" id="ri_form">
              Full Name: <input name="full_name" type="text"><br />
              Email: <input name="email_address_" type="text"><br />
              Gender: <input name="gender" type="text"><br />
              Locale: <input name="locale" type="text"><br />
          </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone clue me in on what I may be doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: What does make you think having **two** `<html>` elements in your page would be beneficial …? Remove the first one, it’s nonsense.

> In IE 8 when I click the login button nothing happens at all.

IE < 9 does not support `addEventListener` to bind event handlers to DOM elements. So unless you’re also embedding some library that adds this capability to older IE (which I’m seeing nothing of), your code can’t work this way … and should actually throw an error in the JS console. (Did you even bother to look there at all?)

Comment: CBroe - I appreciate the help and I have it working now.  To answer your question regarding the JS console - no I didn't bother; I don't do much work with JS ans wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: i've scoured the internet looking for this answer only to find that `addEventListener` was the problem for IE 7/8.... Thanks for saving my sanity